# Android: activity transition

Tags: android, webview

I have a `ListView` that, when clicked, launches a new `Activity` that contains a `WebView`.
Background color of my application is always black but when the user taps on a `ListView` item, the background color becomes white for a while then black again because i've set `#000000` as background color for `WebView` and for the news `Activity`.
Is there a way to avoid the "white transition"?

Comment: This post can be useful: http://www.hambonious.com/2010/06/customizing-android-listview-colors.html

Comment: is the background color of the whole listview to change or the single row?

Answer (score 1):

//for that you need to set the

cacheColor as transparent        `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"`

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/my_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/horizontalline"
    android:background="#000000" 
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" 
    android:layout_above="@id/AddButton"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
     />
```